# What is the optimal index for this DB table?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table for storing stats. Currently this is populated with about 10 million rows at the end of the day then copied to daily stats table and deleted. For this reason I can't have an auto-incrementing primary key.

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `stats` (
`shop_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`mobile` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`click` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`conversion` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ip` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
KEY `shop_id` (`shop_id`,`created`,`ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have a key on `shop_id, created, ip` but I'm not sure what columns I should use to create the optimal index to increase lookup speeds any further?

The query below takes about 12 seconds with no key and about 1.5 seconds using the index above:

```
SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`created`, 'UTC', 'Australia/Brisbane')) AS `date`, COUNT(*) AS `views`
FROM `stats`
WHERE `created` <= '2017-07-18 09:59:59'
AND `shop_id` = '17515021'
AND `click` != 1
AND `conversion` != 1
GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`created`, 'UTC', 'Australia/Brisbane'))
ORDER BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`created`, 'UTC', 'Australia/Brisbane'));
```

Comment: You have created then shop_id then click and so on... in your where clause.
Create the index in same order.

Comment: KEY created_shopid_click_conversion (created,shop_id, click, conversion);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If there is no column (or combination of columns) that is guaranteed unique, then *do* have an `AUTO_INCREMENT id`.  Don't worry about truncating/deleting.  (However, if the id does not reset, you probably need to use `BIGINT`, not `INT UNSIGNED` to avoid overflow.)
- Don't use `id` as the primary key, instead, `PRIMARY KEY(shop_id, created, id), INDEX(id)`.
- That unconventional PK will help with performance in 2 ways, while being unique (due to the addition of `id`).  The `INDEX(id)` is to keep `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy.  (Whether you `DELETE` hourly or daily is a separate issue.)
- Build a Summary table based on each hour (or minute).  It will contain the count for such -- 400K/hour or 7K/minute.  Augment it each hour (or minute) so that you don't have to do all the work at the end of the day.
- The summary table can also filter on click and/or conversion.  *Or* it could keep both, if you need them.
- If click/conversion have only two states (0 & 1), don't say `!= 1`, say `= 0`; the optimizer is much better at `=` than at `!=`.
- If they 2-state and you changed to `=`, then this becomes viable and much better: `INDEX(shop_id, click, conversion, created)` -- `created` must be last.
- Don't bother with TZ when summarizing into the Summary table; apply the conversion later.
- Better yet, don't use DATETIME, use TIMESTAMP so that you won't need to convert (assuming you have TZ set correctly).

After all that, if you still have issues, start over on the Question; there may be further tweaks.

Answer (score -1):

In your where clause, Use the column first which will return the small set of results and so on and create the index in the same order.
You have
`WHERE created <= '2017-07-18 09:59:59'
AND shop_id = '17515021'
AND click != 1
AND conversion != 1`

If created will return the small number of set as compare to other 3 columns then you are good otherwise you that column at first position in your where clause then select the second column as per the same explanation and create the index as per you where clause.
If you think order is fine then create an index

`KEY created_shopid_click_conversion (created,shop_id, click, conversion);`.

Comment: The order in `WHERE` does _not_ matter.  The order in `KEY` _does_ matter.  And a range (`created`) should not (with rare exceptions) be first in the index.